# Trouble renaming file in directory without error: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Tags: java, ioexception, filesystemexception

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
//import java.lang.Object;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

public class AppendTool {
public static void main(String[] args){
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Directory to Append Values: ");
    String dirInput = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Input value to append to Directory Files: ");
    String valInput = sc.nextLine();
    
    sc.close();
    
    Path source = Paths.get(dirInput);
    
    File path = new File(dirInput);

    File [] files = path.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        if (files[i].isFile()){ //this line weeds out other directories/folders
            System.out.println(files[i]);
       try {     
           // int where = files[i].getName().lastIndexOf(".");
            String result = valInput + files[i].getName();//.substring(0, where) + files[i].getName().substring(where);
            System.out.println(result);
            File dest = new File(result);
           //Files.move(files[i].toPath(), dest.toPath().resolveSibling(dest.getName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);   
            Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling(dest.getName()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            System.out.println(dest);
            return;
       } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
            }   
    }
  }
 }
```

I'm trying to iterate through all files in a directory and append a value to each filename. Using Files.move creates a FileSystemException and states that the file is being used by another process. Using the commented-out Files.move(files[i].toPath.....) deletes creates the new file, deletes the old one from the directory, but it does not replace the original file. Any help would be appreciated. For the error below, I have a stuff.txt file saved in documents and I wanted to append "e" to the filename.

> C:\Users\Bob\Documents -> C:\Users\Bob\estuff.txt: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:395)
> at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:292)
> at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1426)
> at AppendTool.main(AppendTool.java:36)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the the parameter arguments for the [Files.move()](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/file-io/how-to-rename-move-file-or-directory-in-java) method are wrong. You need to supply the ***full path and file name*** of the source file (the original file name) and the `source.resolveSibling()` method need to be supplied the ***full path and file name*** of the destination file which in this case happens to the the original file name with the desired text inserted into the beginning of it.

Here is a quick example of how to achieve this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input Directory path to modify file names in:");
System.out.print("Directory Path: --> ");
String dirInput = sc.nextLine();

/* 'DO' take the time to ensure that OS file naming rules 
   are strictly followed when accepting User Input!!   */
System.out.print("Enter the text you want to insert into\n"
               + "the begining of each file name within\n"
               + "this directory: --> ");
String valInput = sc.nextLine();

// Close ONLY if you won't ever need it again in this application.
sc.close(); 
System.out.println();
    
File path = new File(dirInput);
File[] files = path.listFiles();

for (File file : files) {
    if (!file.isFile()) { continue; }
    Path source = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
    File newName = new File(file.getParent() + File.separator + valInput + file.getName());
    System.out.println(newName.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling(newName.getAbsolutePath()),
                                       StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```